# Using current() to establish key value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT

```
<xsl:key name="keyNodeUQ" match="Node" use="concat(UniqueId, '|', ../Node[@id = current()/ParentNode/@ref]/UniqueId)"/>
```

What I'm trying to do is create keys that are the unique id of a node plus the unique id of it's parent node.  The XML has a structure as follows:

```
<Nodes>
    ...
    <Node id="4633">
        <UniqueId>0010BAHGB</UniqueId>
        <ParentNode ref="4575"/>
    </Node>
    <Node id="4575">
        <UniqueId>K005HGBGKV</UniqueId>
    </Node>
    ...
<Nodes>
```

The key is used to discover the unique relationships between child-parent based on their unique ids, and not their id attribute.  If I try to check if this entry exists later on with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('keyNodeUQ', '0010BAHGB|K005HGBGKV'))"/>
```

I am getting 0.  Is the use of current() in the use attribute for creating keys valid?  I've also tried referring to the context node instead of the current node using ., but this doesn't appear to work either.  Any suggestions on how to properly construct the use statement would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using different key names. Is this intentional?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I was formatting.  The proper key name is keyNodeUQ.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the use current() in the use attribute for creating keys valid?

AFAIK, is is not. `current()` is context-based. A key has no context.

---

### Added:

The [XSLT 2.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) is somewhat clearer in this aspect than XSLT 1.0:

> The [use attribute] expression will be evaluated with the node that matches the
>   pattern as the context node.

---

Here's a small demo:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <group type="Alpha" >
        <item>Bravo</item>
        <item>Charlie</item>
    </group>
    <group type="Delta" >
        <item>Echo</item>
        <item>Delta</item>
    </group>
    <group type="Foxtrot" >
        <item>Golf</item>
    </group>
</input>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="group" use="item = current()/@type" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('k', 'true' )"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<output>
   <group type="Delta">
            <item>Echo</item>
            <item>Delta</item>
      </group>
</output>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this situation I'd define a subsidiary key to look up `Node` elements by id and then use that in the definition of the main keyNodeUQ:

```
<xsl:key name="keyNodeId" match="Node" use="@id"/>

<xsl:key name="keyNodeUQ" match="Node"
  use="concat(UniqueId, '|', key('keyNodeId', ParentNode/@ref)/UniqueId)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This is one of the first things that I tried.  It however, results in the error: Invalid function call: recursive key() calls are not allowed.  I asked a question about this error yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369533/invalid-function-call-recursive-key-calls-are-not-allowed-when-using-xslt-bu

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how to properly construct the use statement would
>   be appreciated.

IMHO, instead of nesting the key *elements*, you should nest the key *functions* - for example:

```
<xsl:key name="node-by-ref" match="Node" use="@id"/>
<xsl:key name="node-by-uid" match="Node" use="UniqueId"/>
```

and then:

```
<xsl:variable name="node-uid">0010BAHGB</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="parent-uid">K005HGBGKV</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="key('node-by-ref', key('node-by-uid', $node-uid)/ParentNode/@ref)/UniqueId = $parent-uid"/>
```

will return true.

---

Or, if you prefer, define the keys this way:

```
<xsl:key name="node-by-uid" match="Node" use="UniqueId"/>
<xsl:key name="node-by-ref|uid" match="Node" use="concat(@id, '|', UniqueId)"/>
```

and then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('node-by-ref|uid', concat(key('node-by-uid', $node-uid)/ParentNode/@ref, '|', $parent-uid)))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of current() is legal and correct, even in XSLT 1.0.

In specifying the current() function, XSLT 1.0 says: "For an outermost expression (an expression not occurring within another expression), the current node is always the same as the context node.", and in the definition of "current node" it says that the current node doesn't change unless otherwise specified.

Furthermore, in the definition of xsl:key, it says: "when the expression specified in the use attribute of the xsl:key element is evaluated with x as the current node...."

So if this isn't working then it looks to me as if your XSLT processor is non-conformant.

(OK, what do you do about it? Ideally, change to a different processor. But that starts to be a strategy question rather than a coding question. If you have to work around bugs in your XSLT processor, that's probably a question of trial and error to see what works.)